# Use coffeescripted-sbt to compile coffeescript in multi-project build

Tags: coffeescript, sbt

I have a multi project sbt build and I would like to use https://github.com/softprops/coffeescripted-sbt to compile my coffeescript to javascript, but it is not performing the tasks.

The code was taken from https://github.com/jeffmay/angular-play-multimodule-seed/tree/stackoverflow-17289043

## With build.sbt

Even though it is not recommended, I mixed a build.sbt file in the project directory with my project objects in order to test if this plugin worked.

In `build.sbt`:

```
seq(coffeeSettings: _*)
```

When I ran:

```
$ sbt
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/jeffmay/code/righttrack/project
[info] Set current project to root (in build file:/Users/jeffmay/code/righttrack/)
> coffee
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Jun 24, 2013 11:40:37 PM
> show coffee
[info] ArrayBuffer()
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Jun 24, 2013 11:40:52 PM
> project web
[info] Set current project to web (in build file:/Users/jeffmay/code/righttrack/)
[web] $ coffee
[error] Not a valid command: coffee
[error] No such setting/task
[error] coffee
[error]       ^
[web] $
```

What does `ArrayBuffer()` mean? Is that a silent failure (coffeescript returning the last expression that would otherwise be a `return;` of `null`?)

## Multi Project Setup

For some context, my build is broken out like so...

In `project/plugins.sbt`:

```
// SBT community plugin resolver
resolvers += Resolver.url("sbt-plugin-releases",
  new URL("http://scalasbt.artifactoryonline.com/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)

// CoffeeScript compiler plugin
addSbtPlugin("me.lessis" % "coffeescripted-sbt" % "0.2.3")
```

In `project/Modules.scala` (my build object):

```
import sbt._

object Modules extends Build {

  lazy val root = RootModule.project

  lazy val api = ApiModule.project

  lazy val web = WebModule.project
}
```

In the `project/WebModule.scala`:

```
object WebModule extends BaseModule {

  // ... libraries dependencies and stuff

  override def project = play.Project(moduleName, moduleVersion, libraries, file(location),
    moduleSettings ++
    Seq((resourceManaged in (Compile, CoffeeKeys.coffee)) <<= (crossTarget in Compile)(_ / "src" / "main" / "coffee"))
  )
}
```

I use a `project/BaseModule.scala` to remove the clutter of the common elements of each module, but it isn't doing anything fancy.

## With Build.scala

I remove the `build.sbt` stuff and put it into `Build.scala` via `project/WebModule.scala` by adding:

```
  override def project = play.Project(moduleName, moduleVersion, libraries, file(location),
    moduleSettings ++
    coffeeSettings ++  // With the settings moved from build.sbt
    Seq((resourceManaged in (Compile, CoffeeKeys.coffee)) <<= (crossTarget in Compile)(_ / "src" / "main" / "coffee"))
  )
```

Then I give it a whirl

```
$ sbt
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/jeffmay/code/righttrack/project
[info] Set current project to root (in build file:/Users/jeffmay/code/righttrack/)
> coffee
[error] Not a valid command: coffee
[error] No such setting/task
[error] coffee
[error]       ^
> project web
[info] Set current project to web (in build file:/Users/jeffmay/code/righttrack/)
[web] $ coffee
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Jun 25, 2013 12:08:36 AM
[web] $ show coffee
[info] ArrayBuffer()
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Jun 25, 2013 12:08:40 AM
```

I'm not seeing any changes after running the coffee command. Any ideas what the problem is?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my dialog with softprops for more details: https://github.com/softprops/coffeescripted-sbt/issues/17

There were three problems with and one improvement to the code above.

1. I wasn't aggregating my web project into the root project.
2. I wasn't setting where to find the coffee script files.
3. Play uses "./app" as the `sourceDirectory`, so when I added the seemingly "correct" directory path of

   ```
   sourceDirectory in (Compile, CoffeeKeys.coffee) <<= sourceDirectory { _ / "main" / "coffee" }
   ```

   It was searching in "./app/src/main/coffee", which doesn't exist

I was able to improve this example by having the compiler manage the `./public` directory, so that it could drop the compiled javascript sources in the recommended `public/js` directory for the Angular Seed Project.

You can see the full seed project example here: https://github.com/jeffmay/angular-play-multimodule-seed